# Why is not this gridview loading the results?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I am trying to fill the gridview with the search results. Here is the UI of my "AddDropClasses" page:

[image]

When this page is loaded, i want the gridview to be filled the current courses of the current user, and i do this using the Register table. Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
    con.Open();

    string query = "select * from RegisterTable where StudentID='" + MyGlobals.currentID + "'";

    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

    DataTable tab = new DataTable();

    adap.Fill(tab);

    showCourses.DataSource = tab;


}
```

I load (come to) this page by clicking a button from another page. The problem is, the table shows no results. When i debugged i realized that Myglobals.ID has the value what i already expect. What can be the problem here? Can anyone help?;

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to databind `showCourses`. Add `showCourses.DataBind();` after `showCourses.DataSource = tab;`

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Can you briefly explain also what databinding does?

Comment: For any asp.net databound control, you need to call `DataBind()` which actually populates the control. Have a look at [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_binding.htm), [here](http://sqlmag.com/aspnet/data-binding-aspnet-web-forms) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)