# Gridview selected value always returns 0?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I am trying to delete a row from a gridview if "Web drop course" option is selected. Here is the UI:

[image]

And the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < showCourses.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        if (((DropDownList)showCourses.Rows[i].FindControl("actionmenu")).SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            dropList.Add(showCourses.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text +showCourses.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text );
        }
    }
```

Here is the dropdown list:

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">No Action</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Web Drop Course</asp:ListItem>
```

The problem is, `((DropDownList)showCourses.Rows[i].FindControl("actionmenu")).SelectedValue` always returns 0 whether I choose `No action` or `Web drop course`. Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Comment: what is the values of your dropodwnlist?

Comment: <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">No Action</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Web Drop Course</asp:ListItem>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879338/why-is-not-this-gridview-loading-the-results/16879366#16879366), you are rebinding the gridview on each postback. Wrap those lines with a `!IsPostback` conditional. Better wrap those into a method (say `PopulateGrid()`) and call it. Then, you can re-call that method in other situations where you might need to rebind the data (`OnPageIndexChanged` for example). Change your `Page_Load` method like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateGrid();
    }
}

private void PopulateGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        string query = "select * from RegisterTable where StudentID='" + MyGlobals.currentID + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable tab = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(tab);
        showCourses.DataSource = tab;
        showCourses.DataBind();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, which lines are you talking about? Can you show them please?

Comment: Thank you, but now it does not even enter into the if block

Comment: Oh soryy, i will try again it now

Comment: Thanks, when i also added the showCourses.DataBind(); into the if block it worked

Comment: Welcome. Code is modified; `DataBind()` added and a `using` block is in place (which is a good practice).

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely not protecting against rebinding your data on postback. When your event that causes postback fires, the page load event fires before this. If you are binding in page load without a check for postback, you are basically resetting your data and then going into your event handler.

The page life cycle might be a good read:  [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but so what should i do now? How can i do it?

Comment: As @mshsayem mentioned, wrap your binding inside a `!IsPostback` if block.